# Junit5 test suites with @Suite annotation doesn't execute tests with mvn test command

Tags: junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

We intended to upgrade a JUnit4 based project to JUnit5. I modified JUnit4 suites according to the instruction in JUnit5 official site: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-junit-platform-runner-test-suite.
Tests were not executed when using mvn test in command line: `mvn test -Dtest=SuiteXXTest`, neither in JUnit4 nor JUnit5 suite.
Error msg: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project XXX: No tests were executed!`
Yet both JUnit4 and JUnit5 suites can run and execute the included tests in IDEA. Maven surefire plugin version is `3.0.0-M5`. Single test classes(ATest and BTest) are based on JUnit4 progamming model.

Old JUnit4 suite is like this:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import test.XX.*;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        ATest.class,
        BTest.class
})
public class SuiteXXTest {
}
```

Modified to:

```
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasses;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;
import test.XX.*;

@Suite
@SelectClasses({
            ATest.class,
            BTest.class
})
public class SuiteXXTest {

}
```

related dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
```

Curiously, if I use the depracated @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) annotation, the test suites can execute properly. But according to JUnit5 official user guide, using this runner means tests will be executed in a JUnit4 envrionment, and I don't understand what condition is regarded as JUnit4 environment(JUnit5 dependency already configured in pom).

I don't known if it's a bug or my incorrect use.

Comment: And I also tried modify ATest and BTest to JUnit5 programming model, it still won't work.

Answer (score 1):

`RunWith` is a JUnit 4 construct and won’t work with JUnit 5. Use JUnit Platform suites instead as described in https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#junit-platform-suite-engine

Comment: What I'm having problem with is this in JUnit5 programming style suite:

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasses;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;
import test.XX.*;

@Suite
@SelectClasses({
            ATest.class,
            BTest.class
})
public class SuiteXXTest {

}

Comment: Code in a comment is unreadable. Add it to your question if it is relevant. Have you read the link and tried it? If yes, what exactly did not work?

Comment: Sorry for the unreadable code. It's just same as the JUnit5 style suite in my description above. I actually have read the the link you give before I post this question. The junit-platform-suite is already used in my pom.xml, and junit-platform-suite-engine is its transitive dependency. The problem is test suites with @Suite annotation in JUnit5 style won't execute tests in command like "mvn test -Dtest=SuiteXXTest".

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/discussions/2753.

According to this answer I just changed my command from `-Dtest=SuiteXXTest` to `-Dinclude=SuiteXXTest` and it works fine. I think it has something to do with the surefire plugin. It seems surefire cannot pick up tests form suite annotated with `@Suite` when using `-Dtest` command.

Comment: -Dtest=SuiteXXTest is a filter in the junit runner hierarchy and that's why it does not work as you like. The -Dinclude=SuiteXXTest is a file scanner and that's why it works.

Comment: Curiously, this did not work for me. When I just changed "-Dtest=" to "-Dinclude=", it simply ran all of my unit tests and ignored the test suite that I specified.

Answer (score 0):

strange, I had the same problem, and when changing from surefire 3.1.2 back to 2.22.2 it worked, i.e. adds all test back to the test reports and does not generate individual tests.