# Maven JUnit 5: Run all unit tests by default or run only a specific test suite from the command line

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit5

We are upgrading our services to a relatively recent SpringBoot version, along with JUnit 5.  We normally run our builds with just "mvn package", which runs all of our unit tests by default.

We also have "component tests", which are run from a separate command line, and which are all specified in a single test suite with a specific name.  Before JUnit 5, we would run this with something like:

```
mvn -Dtest=ComponentTestSuite test
```

This was working fine with JUnit 4.

The class looks like this:

```
@Suite
@SelectClasses(<testclassname>.class)
public class ComponentTestSuite {
}
```

With JUnit 5, this ends up saying "No tests found".

We are using v2.3.12 of Spring-Boot, which by default includes a somewhat older version of JUnit 5.  I am overriding those defaults and including v1.8.2 of the junit-platform components and v5.8.2 of the jupiter components.

For the service that I'm testing this with, the test suite only has a single component test (which is unusual).  I WAS able to simply replace "ComponentTestSuite" with the name of the component test class, and that would run that single component test.

I noticed this thread: [Junit5 test suites with @Suite annotation doesn't execute tests with mvn test command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70299502/junit5-test-suites-with-suite-annotation-doesnt-execute-tests-with-mvn-test-co) .

Unfortunately, what I found was that changing "-Dtest" to "-Dinclude" simply ran all my default unit tests and ignored the test suite.

Comment: Hey David, I voted to close as this can be done now with tags. You can also check the junit [documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-tags) - in particular if you'll have multiple component tests.

Comment: I'll just have to post a new question asking how to get tags working, because it's not.

Comment: And by the way, this should never have been closed. The Surefire maintainers determined that not being able to execute a testsuite from the command line was a bug. They have already created a PR to fix the problem, which will be in the next release.