# Maven JUnit 5: Using JUnit5 tags, run all unit tests by default or run only a specific test suite from the command line

Tags: maven, junit, junit5

I posted this: [Maven JUnit 5: Run all unit tests by default or run only a specific test suite from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71504947/maven-junit-5-run-all-unit-tests-by-default-or-run-only-a-specific-test-suite-f) .

I'm simply posting it again with almost exactly the same title because nothing about my base problem has changed, but I will include what I tried to do with Tags, which are not working for me.

We are upgrading our services to a relatively recent SpringBoot version, along with JUnit 5. We normally run our builds with just "mvn package", which runs all of our unit tests by default.

We also have "component tests", which are run from a separate command line, and which are all specified in a single test suite with a specific name. Before JUnit 5, we would run this with something like:

```
mvn -Dtest=ComponentTestSuite test
```

This was working fine with JUnit 4.

The class looks like this:

```
@Suite
@SelectClasses(<testclassname>.class)
public class ComponentTestSuite {
}
```

With JUnit 5, this ends up saying "No tests found".

We are using v2.3.12 of Spring-Boot, which by default includes a somewhat older version of JUnit 5. I am overriding those defaults and including v1.8.2 of the junit-platform components and v5.8.2 of the jupiter components.

For the service that I'm testing this with, the test suite only has a single component test (which is unusual). I WAS able to simply replace "ComponentTestSuite" with the name of the component test class, and that would run that single component test.

I noticed this thread: [Junit5 test suites with @Suite annotation doesn't execute tests with mvn test command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70299502/junit5-test-suites-with-suite-annotation-doesnt-execute-tests-with-mvn-test-co) .

Unfortunately, what I found was that changing "-Dtest" to "-Dinclude" simply ran all my default unit tests and ignored the test suite.

So, I was told that I'm "not supposed to do it this way", although it's not clear to me exactly which parts I'm not supposed to do, but I am supposed to use "Tags".  Ok, so I tried to use tags.

I also noticed this article: https://www.baeldung.com/junit-filtering-tests , although that article appears to use some deprecated mechanisms, like "@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)", so I'm not sure how much I can believe from that article.

I've been trying several variations, and my last attempt is this:

```
@Suite
@Tag("ComponentTest")
@IncludeTags("ComponentTest")
public class ComponentTestSuite {
}
```

And I added `@Tag("ComponentTest")` to my one component test class.

This still doesn't work.  I try to run `mvn -Dtest=ComponentTestSuite test`, and it says "No tests found".  If I instead try `mvn -Dtests=ComponentTest test`  that just runs all of my unit tests and ignores my component test suite.  If I instead run `mvn test -Dgroups=ComponentTest`, that gives me another variation of "No tests found" in that it doesn't print that, it just literally executes no tests without giving an error.

Looking at that suite class now, it does seem nonsensical, as it doesn't really "contain" anything anymore, which is unfortunate.  It was good to have that list of component test classes in one place.  Now, it seems like the suite class is pointless, but I can't get anything to work anyway.

Note that I haven't yet added a "groups" element to my surefire config, and I haven't edited all of my unit tests to add a `@Tag("UnitTest")` annotation. I've only edited the suite class and the one component test.

Update:

To address a comment, I am specifying the following dependencies (among others):

Version 1.8.2 of

- junit-platform-suite
- junit-platform-suite-api
- junit-platform-launcher
- junit-platform-commons
- junit-platform-engine
- junit-platform-runner
- junit-platform-suite-engine

Version 5.8.2 of

- junit-jupiter
- junit-bom (probably unnecessary)

The entire suite class is this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeTags;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasses;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

@Suite
@Tag("ComponentTest")
@IncludeTags("ComponentTest")
public class ComponentTestSuite {
}
```

Comment: Sorry for closing the other question, I though moving to tags would be the best solution to your problem. Do you have the junit5 suite dependencies? (`junit- platform-suite-api` and `junit-platform-suite-engine`). Please also check that you are using the new suite annotations and not the ones from junit4 as described [here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/index.html#junit-platform-suite-engine)